# Persistent PySpark Dataframe from a Hive query

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm getting some data from a Hive table:

```
df = sqlContext.sql('select shubiru, date from thebigtable bt where bt.num > 10 ')
df.show() # here the query is processed and the results shown
```

and that's working fine. Now I want to operate over df, but every time I do an operation over df, it runs again the query against Hive:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType

dt_udt = func.udf(lambda x: datetime.strptime(str(x), '%Y%m%d') if x else None, TimestampType())
df = df.withColumn('fdate', dt_udt(df.date)) 
df.show()  # here the query is run again and the transformation is done
```

So I would think that if I call `persist` on df, the query would not be run again:

```
df.cache()
df = df.withColumn('fdate', dt_udf(df.date))
```

but no dice, the query is run again against Hive and processed by the UDF. Is there a way to cache in memory the results of the query and run operations over the dataframe without hitting Hive everytime?

Answer (score 1):

Spark SQL pulls the data from the DataSource(in your case Hive) whenever an operation is performed on the data. In this case you are trying to rename column after `cache()` which would be useless. My suggestion would be to have something like

```
df = df.withColumn('fdate', dt_udf(df.date)).withColumn('date_column_2', dt_udf(df.date)).cache()
```

All your operations after this statement would operate on the data persisted in spark. However caching large amounts of data would automatically evict older RDD partitions and would need to go back to hive to regenerate the lost partitions.

Comment: Thanks. Why the second `withColumn`? I'm not trying to rename the `date` column, I'm trying to transform it with a new format.